# SQL How to check a sum of multiple rows and tables without join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables. One with workorders, one with material that is planned and one with material that has been issued.

#### T1:Workorders

WONUM

#### T2:Planned material

WONUM, ITEM, QUANTITY

#### T3:Issued material

WONUM, ITEM, QUANTITY

I have managed to select all workorders which have material planned but no material issued with simple exits query (we can not join tables).

```
 and exists (select * from T2 where T2.WONUM = T1.WONUM)
 and not exists (select * from T3 where T3.WONUM = T1.WONUM)
```

I can also select workorders which have material issued with mostly the same basical query.

```
 and exists (select * from T2 where T2.WONUM = T1.WONUM)
 and exists (select * from T3 where T3.WONUM = T1.WONUM)
```

But what I now want is to `select all workorders from T1 where the sum of T3.QUANTITY + T2.QUANTITY is 0`. (`T3.QUANTITY` contains for example `-3` if there are `3` units issued)

I am not allowed to use `JOIN` to create a view so I have to do some nested query.
I have also tried to use the `DUAL` table to `sum`, but it can only handle 1 row.

Comment: Why can't you use `JOIN` to create a view?  This is definitely not an Oracle restriction.

Comment: Can you use OUTER APPLY?  or UNION?   I assume you are using SQL syntax in Oracle?  Or is this a general DB question?

Comment: Corelated sub queries perhaps...Is the JOIN restriction purely an exercise?

Comment: You can do subqueries in the WHERE clause: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4c371/4

Comment: We cant use join because the query runs from the webinterface and its not allowed. 
From an databasemanager i can use join, but i have to create so that the users can run the query from the webinterface

Comment: @Grantly: **of course** he is using "SQL syntax" in Oracle - SQL is the only query language that Oracle supports

Comment: Thanks not-very-helpful-horse, or he could be using SQL in general or in psuedo code or in SQL Server or in MySQL, or posing a question for any SQL based language not specifically Oracle.  Oracle has some juicy features only available in Oracle...Hence my query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
 and ((select SUM(t2.quantity) from T2 where T2.WONUM = T1.WONUM) +
      (select SUM(t3.quantity) from T3 where T3.WONUM = T1.WONUM)
     ) = 0
```

Actually, because there could be no match, you need to handle `NULL` values:

```
 and (coalesce((select SUM(t2.quantity) from T2 where T2.WONUM = T1.WONUM), 0) +
      coalesce((select SUM(t3.quantity) from T3 where T3.WONUM = T1.WONUM), 0)
     ) = 0
```

Comment: It worked but the execution time was over 2 minutes so i think i have to find another soloution.

Comment: You should probably create a view in the database that uses the correct constructs (it should be more efficient).  Users can then access the view.  If you know `quantity` is never negative, you can significantly increase the performance of this method.

Answer (score 0):

please try:

     `SELECT CASE WHEN NVL
  (((SELECT SUM (NVL (T2.QUANTITY), 0)
       FROM T2
      WHERE T2.WONUM = T1.WONUM) +
    (SELECT SUM (NVL (T3.QUANTITY), 0)
       FROM T3
      WHERE T3.WONUM = T1.WONUM), 0) = 0)
       THEN T1.WONUM
       ELSE NULL AS FOO
       FROM T1;`

I didn't test it, sorry. I'm typing from small android phone in a fast-moving jetty.

Comment: It worked, but now i have access to a view that i can design with joins so the problem got solved anyway.